# USB Mass Storage Not Working

Tags: usb, motorola-droid, storage, usb-connection-mode, usb-mass-storage

I have spent a few hours trying to figure out why my USB mass storage function is not working with my laptop. Here's what I've done:

- Installed Android 2.3.2 (Pete's GPA12)
- Uninstalled, cleaned, and reinstalled drivers from Motorola.
- Reinstalled Java JDK
- Rebooted

After through all this, it still doesn't work.

Motorola Droid

Windows 7 x64

Comment: Related: [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/218526)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found out what's wrong. I had USB Debugging enabled at the same time so I had to turn that off and now it works.

Menu > Settings > Applications > Development > USB Debugging