# Successfully activated USB host mode using terminal emulator; now mass storage won't work

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb-connection-mode, usb-host-mode, huawei-u8160, usb-mass-storage

I have a Huawei u8160 running Cyanogenmod 7.2 .

I've recently been digging into USB host mode and I finally activated it. However when I connect my phone to the PC it doesn't give me a notification about "USB connected". It only charges the phone (that means it's connected).

---

How I activate USB host mode :

```
su
insmod /system/lib/modules/ehci-hcd.ko
```

or by using [Module Loader App](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1228605).

---

How I tried to deactivate USB host mode (which failed):

```
su
rmmod ehci_hcd
```

and when I list the mods using `lsmod` it returns that ehci_hcd mod isn't there

My question here is how can I deactivate the mode in a way that USB Mass Storage would work?

---

**NOTE:** I saw [USB Mass Storage Not Working question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6363/usb-mass-storage-not-working) and it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `ehci_hcd`, use `ehci-hcd` instead:

```
su  
rmmod ehci-hcd
```